# Will molten glass stick to a graphite shelf inside a kiln?

Tags: materials

Normally, so called shelf papers are used or special coatings called kiln washes are used to prevent molten glass from adhering to the kiln shelf while it is being fired.  This is expensive and time consuming.  Can a different material be used that will not allow the molten glass to stick to it, such as a type of graphite?  This would also improve the appearance of the backside of the finished glass project.

Comment: Logically, it makes sense that graphite would work, provided you were using a sheet of it and not just carbon paper. If you have the resources I'd recommend performing the experiment and publishing the results.

Comment: At the risk of being obvious... Why not try it and let us know what you find out?

Comment: Since my posting of this question I have learned that graphite sheet/plate 1/4" or so will work for this application, but it suffers degradation over concurrent firings in the kiln.  This degradation will effect the final outcome of the finished work in that a rough surface imminently created which tends to grab the molten glass or at minimum leave a rough finished backside on the glass.  Kiln shelf paper may be the ultimate answer.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure about the use of graphite or other materials for this purpose. However, kiln wash is a low cost solution that should give you the same quality as kiln shelf paper.

http://www.bigceramicstore.com/info/ceramics/tips/tip96_kiln_wash.html

http://ceramicartsdaily.org/firing-techniques/soda-firing/the-many-layers-of-kiln-wash-how-to-find-the-best-kiln-wash-for-your-firing-temperature-and-methods/

Comment: Would it mess with the heating element at all or no